# CentOS - program can't find missing library but ld.conf points to it

Tags: linux, centos, shared-libraries, ld, ldd

When I run ldd on **/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so** I see that it can't find libmysqlclient_r.so.16

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe2dfe000)
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f291c093000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f291ba0a000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f291b706000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f291b345000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f291b129000)
    libicui18n.so.51 => /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicui18n.so.51 (0x00007f291ad10000)
    libicuuc.so.51 => /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicuuc.so.51 (0x00007f291a989000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f291a785000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f291a583000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f291a37a000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f291a04e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2919d4c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2919b35000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003723a00000)
    libicudata.so.51 => /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicudata.so.51 (0x00007f29183ec000)
```

so libmysqlclient_r.so.16 is missing...so I did a " find / -name libmysqlclient_r.so*" and found:

> /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so

So it seems my program is not finding the so file. So I looked in my /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and found the maria conf file containing:

> /usr/lib64/mysql

Doesn't that mean that the linux loader SHOULD find the missing library file? The program above needs libmysqlclient_r.so.16 , and libmysqlclient_r.so is on the LD path provided by /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mariadb-x86_64.conf

What is the missing link here?

---

Update: I added a symlink from the .so.16 to the .so but still not resolved:

```
[root@dev mysql]# ldd /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so | grep found
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
[root@lt-ms-fedora64 mysql]# ll
total 3052
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      17 Mar 18 15:26 libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmysqlclient.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      17 Mar 18 17:52 libmysqlclient_r.so.16 -> libmysqlclient.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      20 Mar 18 15:26 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.18
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      17 Mar 18 17:51 libmysqlclient.so.16 -> libmysqlclient.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      24 Mar 13 19:51 libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3114608 Feb  5 13:06 libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    6946 Feb  5 13:04 mysql_config
[root@dev mysql]# pwd
/usr/lib64/mysql
[root@dev mysql]# ldd /opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so | grep found
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
[root@lt-ms-fedora64 mysql]# ldconfig
```

and "ldconfig -v | more" shows (just partial):

```
/usr/lib64/llvm:
    libLTO.so -> libLTO.so
    libLLVM-3.3.so -> libLLVM-3.3.so
    libprofile_rt.so -> libprofile_rt.so
/usr/lib64/mysql:
    libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient_r.so.16
/usr/lib64/tracker-0.16:
    libtracker-data.so.0 -> libtracker-data.so.0.1600.1
    libtracker-common.so.0 -> libtracker-common.so.0.1600.1
/usr/lib64/xulrunner:
    libmozalloc.so ->
```

I don't understand that line **libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient_r.so.16** - why is the _r.so.16 not listed?  I'm close...just can't figure out the last bit!

Comment: You've found libmysqlclient_r.so , but you need libmysqlclient_r.so.16 , /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so is might be a dangling symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the risk of pointing out the obvious:

```
.16
```

Create a symlink to the .so and try again.

Comment: I tried that (see update above), but still not working

Comment: OK, apologies. I assumed you knew enough Linux to know that doing this kind of stuff requires a run of 'ldconfig' to make the system aware of such changes.  If that STILL doesn't work: what are the chances of the library you installed being the wrong architecture?

Comment: I did an ldconfig (I added more lines above) and then ldconfig -v to see what it picked up.  I don't quite know enough to understand the output though